# How to enable the softInput on the editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode

I disabled softInput on my editText using

```
public static void disableSoftInputFromAppearing(EditText editText) {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    }
```

But now I don't know how to enable it. A function to enable the softInput would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

from [this](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)